# Heroku Django db postgres error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to get my first django app up, but I'm running into this db error:

```
OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

This happens whenever I try to syncdb, migrate, or createsuperuser

I am configuring my DATABASES variable like:

```
DATABASES = {'default' : dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ["HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL"]) }
```

Is there something else I need to configure or am doing wrong?

EDIT (SOLVED):

Thanks for helping me narrow down the problem, I've found the solution.

Since this was the first time I deployed to heroku and the first time I used the two scoops django directory format.  I thought doing something like

```
python manage.py syncdb # would be okay
```

instead beause my settings folder looks like

```
.../settings
    base.py
    local.py
    production.py
    demo.py
    # ...
```

I need to do

```
python manage.py syncdb --app.settings.demo
```

Comment: Are you sure "HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL" is defined? Heroku has several database options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax seems right, try using `DATABASE_URL` after verifying you promoted `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL`, although it should work even when not promoted.

```
$ heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL
```

and then:

```
import dj_database_url

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.getenv('DATABASE_URL'))
}
```

This setup should be working. Else, check that you are working on the right settings file. You can verify this by running:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py shell
```

and then:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> print settings.DATABASES['default']
```

and verify result.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error in .gitignore and my local settings were getting set by Heroku by mistake.

This will also cause this error message message.