# OperationalError could not connect to server

Tags: django, heroku-postgres

I put a Django app on Heroku recently. The home page looks fine, but when I try to go to a page that involves making a query (e.g. `p = Photo.objects.get(title=title)`), I get this error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

In accordance with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12126242/1763621), I did `$ heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN_URL`

Then in my settings.py:

`DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])}`

Still got the same error, so I tried looking at the results of this (as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16418493/1763621) suggests):

```
$ heroku run python manage.py shell

>>> from django.conf import settings

>>> print settings.DATABASES['default']

{'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC', 'TEST_MIRROR': None, 'NAME': 'snorthway', 'OPTIONS': {}, 
'HOST': 'localhost', 'TEST_NAME': None, 'PASSWORD': '******', 'ENGINE': 
'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'PORT': '', 'USER': 'snorthway', 
'TEST_COLLATION': None, 'TEST_CHARSET': None}
```

At which point I realized I don't know what I should even be looking for in that. I still don't understand what the error means, so I am unsure how to go about debugging it.

Comment: Are you able to query the database from the shell? Like importing your models and then running p = Photo.objects.get(title=title) ?

Comment: Nope, I get the same error when I import models and run something like `print Photo.objects.all()`.

Comment: When you run `heroku config`, do you see `DATABASE_URL` in the list of config vars? Also, you shouldn't need the `default=` part; I think it should just be `dj_database_url.config(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])`

Comment: @snorthway try to change `HOST` value from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 3):

You have not configured your django database correctly in settings.py. It thinks your database is on localhost. Sounds like you have a heroku postgres database so your host should be something like:

> df3-64-304-50-250.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Heroku exposes a special database URL through an environment variable called:

> DATABASE_URL

There is a very cool python package here called dj_database_url: https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url it converts that environment variable to what django expects.

you can install it with:

> $pip install dj-database-url

I use the following in my settings.py

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer saved my life!